# Need help to fetch data from a URL parameter using Ajax or Java Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to get the data in a URL parameter and assign it in a `label` in another page.

The URL is: http://localhost:60391/pages/reservations.html?3

I need to fetch that `3` at the end of the URL and assign it to a `label` in my webpage with `ID` `#TestLabel`.

Can anyone help me with the JavaScript/Ajax code to achieve this?

Comment: This is possible but this isn't a code writing service. Please make an attempt on your own and the community will be happy to review it and help you along.

Comment: An MCVE would be great help if we are going to help you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var parts = document.location.href.split("?");
if (parts.length === 2) {
    document.getElementById("TestLabel").textContent = parts[1];
}
```

Comment: `document.location.search.substr(1)` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. that helped. :)